# Getting related Conversation ID from an array of conversation IDs and use it dynamically according to user to whom we send the message in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, messenger

I am trying to create a messenger, and currently trying to implement Send Button.
I have got some users from api and displayed them on the tabs. So when logged in user clicks on the tab it displays its messages.

Send button api requires 2 request params.
1: message
2: conversationId

I have recieved the conversation id, it gets created when I add a new user and display on the browser.

Now the issue is I can send the message params, but during the use of conversation id, it only shows me one id. for example when I click on user 3 and type message and send it still sends message to Cid:1 not related id.

example:

```
Cid = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

So when I loop through this it only gives me one value like 1, not related to user or conversation id:

ts file

```
  sendMessage(){

    if(!this.text){
      return;
    }

    let cid;

    for(let i=0; i<this.conversationID.length; i++){
      cid = this.conversationID[i]
    }

    console.log(cid);

    
    

    this.chatService.add(this.editor.quillEditor.root.innerHTML, cid);
    this.editor.quillEditor.root.innerHTML = '';
  }
```

service file

```
add(message: string, conversationId: number){


        const requestBody = {
            message,
            conversationId
        }

   
        this.http.post('createmessage', requestBody).subscribe((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        })
   
    }
```

html file

```
<button class="ql-send-button" (click)="sendMessage()" [disabled]="!text"><fa-icon [icon]="faMessage"></fa-icon></button>
```

Comment: Instead of looping through the array, just pass the `conversationId` into sendMessage function and assign it `cid`

Comment: I have tried it, then it prints all the conversation id which are in my conversation lists to the request parameters

Comment: "it only shows me one id". Your for loop is like: cid = this.conversationID[this.conversationID.length - 1] then whatever you do you will only get the last value of your array. When you create your tabs, each one should be created with there cId then, when you click on the tab, you should set which is the current cId: for example with a service, inside your tab component, you do messageService.currentCid = this.cid then when you click on "send" you retrieve the cId with messageService.currentCid.

Comment: @Pierre-HenriSudre Your 5 line of sentences works like a charm. Thank you it works :)